# Are weapons that are "effective against birds/beasts/slimes/lizards/undead" really any better?

Tags: secret-of-mana

In Secret of Mana, certain weapons say they are:

- Effective against slimes/lizards
- Effective against birds/beasts
- Effective against plants/fish
- Effective against evil/undead/non-living enemies, or
- Effective against *dragons*

What does this actually *mean?* Does it make any noticeable difference? Does it mean they cause 1% more damage? 10% more? 100% more? Or does the game simply say they're better but they have no effect at all?

Answer (score 2):

From experience of many playthroughs, yes, it makes a difference. Such weapons do noticeably more damage to the relevant type of creature. You can see this by simply using it: since you fight so many things with each iteration of a weapon, you get to know the typical damage numbers that appear, and the damage done to appropriate creatures with an "effective against" weapon is noticeably higher than expected.

The exact math is not available anywhere, as far as I know.